# XNA Game development: Vector2 values randomly change to X:-2147483648 Y:-2147483648

Tags: c#, xna

it happens randomly, I checked my whole code and i don't set position anywhere to numbers like this, here is a screenshot, I am using visual studio 2013 and Windows 7.
Link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vbm7v.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calculating with integers (although the vector2 are floats) but you might have some casts in your code.

See the following max/min values of ints and my example code which looks a lot like the problem you are having.

```
Int32.MaxValue: 2,147,483,647
Int32.MinValue: -2,147,483,648
```

See this example code and the comments with the values:

```
int a = Int32.MaxValue; // a is 2,147,483,647
a++; // after the ++ a is -2,147,483,648
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's fixed, it was problem with camera class when constructing viewMatrix, some mathematical operation was returning NaN.

Comment: Next time use breakpoints or step through the code using the debug-tools to find out where the value is changed.
If you don't see the reason for the problem you can post the code that produces the problem and even the values sent to this "mathematical operation".
This way it is easier for other SO-users to help you find a solution.